# Droppable elements position gets calculated incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table with the class: `.screens`, cells of which are droppable. I can drag any item from the list in its cells. I'm also trying to calculate where user dropped the item so it appears on the right place. But there is a problem, if the user tries to drop the item in any cell except of first one, drop position gets calculated incorrectly. Here is my code for this calculation:

```
var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
var droppedTop = ui.position.top - $(this).offset().top + $('#mainContainer').scrollTop();
var droppedLeft = ui.position.left - $(this).offset().left + $('#mainContainer').scrollLeft();
```

I'm then assigning these top and left positions to the dropped item. This code works perfectly if there is no table, but the div only. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/moafzcx8/2/ Drag and drop items to the table to see the problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You don't have a `#mainContainer`.

Comment: @AndyG I have fixed that in the fiddle, but it does not work. #mainContainer (now #mainDiv) is a parent of this table, which might get scrolled.

Comment: changing this  $('.screenContainer').droppable(....) to  $('.screens').droppable(....). This will set the top and left position based on the whole .screens container, not the individual .screenContainer elements.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze minor improvements to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bwpcph7z/

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze you want the items dropped to be center of the cell?

Comment: @Jim-miraidev Yes, it does. Visually, that's exactly what I want, but if you inspect the element, you will see that in this case dropped items won't be children of $('.screenContainer').

Comment: @Twisty No need them to be centered, user must be able to place them where he wants. Plus they must be draggable. But in the DOM tree they must be children of the cell they were dropped on. That's essential for my next plans in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Little tricky but works fine. The point is, I'm catching drop target cell's X and Y indexes, then find out what are the width and height of each cell before them and add this value to the drop position. Here is the code for this operation:

```
var cellIndexX = event.target.cellIndex;
var cellIndexY = event.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
var positioningX = cellIndexX*($('#0-0').width());
var positioningY = cellIndexY*($('#0-0').height());
```

Then add `positionX` and `positionY` like this:

```
var pos = ui.draggable.offset(), dPos = $(this).offset();
var droppedTop = ui.position.top - $(this).offset().top + $('#mainContainer').scrollTop()+positioningY;
var droppedLeft = ui.position.left - $(this).offset().left + $('#mainContainer').scrollLeft()+positioningX;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do overall. I would advise using jQuery UI `.position()` to help position the item in the cell. Consider this in your `drop`:

```
    var $dz = $(this);
    var fCount = $dz.find(".foo").length;
    var $item = ui.draggable.appendTo($dz);
    var padTop = 5;
    if (fCount === 0) {
      $item.position({
        my: "center top",
        at: "center top+" + padTop,
        of: $dz
      });
    } else {
      var jump = fCount * 42;
      $item.position({
        my: "center top",
        at: "center top+" + (jump + padTop),
        of: $dz
      });
    }
```

This appends the item and also positions it inside the cell. The benefit is that it easily position the item relative to the parent cell and not having to deal with offsets and the like.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bwpcph7z/4/

Comment: Thank you for reply. Pretty close, but I need the dropped items to be draggable anywhere, as it's in my fiddle. The only problem in my code is positioning. Drop position gets calculated by offsets in the '.screenContainer' it got dropped, but items appear in the first cell with correct cell positioning. Meanwhile, it's child of the cell it was dropped on despite where it got dragged. How do I fix this bug, when dropped item appears in the first cell?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze the Working Example shows that this can be done, moving the item from cell to cell. It also addresses the append issue and positioning issue.

Comment: Found a solution, little tricky but pretty easy after all. Check my answer.